# library primefaces doesn't contain component steps

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am beginner in Java and facing a problem using the `p:steps` component.

I can not understand how to get rid the following error:

> Exception : library PrimeFaces doesn't contain component steps

Here's my code :

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">  
<h:head>  
    <title>Cart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>        
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <p:steps>
                <p:menuitem value="Personal" />
                <p:menuitem value="Seat Selection" />
                <p:menuitem value="Payment" />
                <p:menuitem value="Confirmation" />
            </p:steps>
            <h3>Interactive</h3>
            <p:steps activeIndex="1" styleClass="custom" readonly="false">
                <p:menuitem value="Personal" url="#"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Seat Selection" url="#"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Payment" url="#"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Confirmation" url="#"/>
            </p:steps>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
    </section>
</h:body>
```

Comment: which version of primefaces you are using ???

Comment: I am using Primefaces version 3.5

Comment: I suppose its mentioned, actually i'm using primefaces.org showcase for my frontend, and in that documentaion version of primefaces was not mentioned....!!!

Comment: Ohh sorry, i never mean like that. :(  And thanks for your concern.

Comment: Version info IS mentioned in the docs that are used in the showcase. And you can see at the bottom of the page which version the showcase is using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the latest version of PrimeFaces at least  5.1.7 or 5.2 because the step feature is not available in PrimeFaces 3.5. You can use the latest version of PrimeFaces to get all the new tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not supported in newer versions 10 or later.